# Remove "NULL rows" from a String array using LINQ

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

How would you remove "NULL rows" from a String array using LINQ?

Take this structure (`String[,]`):

```
"Hello", "World", "Foo", "Bar"
null,    null,    null,  null
null,    null,    null,  null
"Hello", "World", "Foo", "Bar"
"Hello", "World", "Foo", "Bar"
null,    null,    "Foo", "Bar"
```

The two rows after the first row should be removed. The last row in the structure should not.

Comment: What you are asking for is not possible. If you want to remove items from an array, you HAVE to create a new array and copy the items that you want to keep, even if you use LINQ to do it for you.

Comment: Linq has a hard time iteration over arrays defined in [,]. Do you want this in Linq to prove it can be done, or because a loop is ugly code? Linq might not be the answer to all our problems :)

Comment: @Mikael Svenson: One line of code using LINQ is more readable than a 5-6 line loop.

Comment: @roosteronacid True, if such a one-liner exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the arrays in a List, for instance, you could do this:

```
        IList<string[]> l = new List<string[]>
        {
            new []{ "Hello", "World", "Foo", "Bar" },
            new string[]{ null,    null,    null,  null },
            new string[] { null,    null,    null,  null },
            new [] { "Hello", "World", "Foo", "Bar" },
            new [] {null, null, "Foo", "Bar" }
        };
        var newList = l.Where(a => a.Any(e => e != null));
```

*(update)*

I don't think Linq will give you much assistance with multidimensional arrays. Here's a solution using plain old for loops...

```
        string[,] arr = new string[,] {
            { "Hello", "World", "Foo", "Bar" },
            { null,    null,    null,  null },
            { null,    null,    null,  null },
            { "Hello", "World", "Foo", "Bar" },
            {null, null, "Foo", "Bar" }
        };

        IList<string[]> l = new List<string[]>();

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            string[] aux = new string[arr.GetLength(1)];
            bool isNull = true;
            for (int j = 0; j < arr.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                aux[j] = arr[i, j];
                isNull &= (aux[j] == null);
            }
            if (!isNull)
                l.Add(aux);
        }
```

This results in a `List<string[]>`.

Comment: As you are querying the newly created empty list, it will return an empty result...

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do this, arrays are a fixed size, you would need a new array, a list or collection can have things removed in this manner.

Arrays cannot. You need to have something in those rows.

Any solutions calling something like toArray() are constructing an array which is what you specifically asked not to happen.

Comment: Updated my question. What I want is a one-line'r using LINQ.