# How to create a Dictionary from an Array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

okay have a this list:

```
object[] test;
test[0]=null;
....
test[8700]=null;
test[8701]= object[]
....
test[9431]= object[]
```

where object[] is another list with either the value true/false/null

i need to convert this array into a list/dictinary containing only values without null:

```
Dictionary<int, object> dic = new Dictionary<int,object>;
```

or

```
list<Sector> sectors= new list<Sector>()
```

where sector looks like this

```
Sector{(int)id,(List<Product>)products}
Product{(int)id}
```

what will be the best/smartest way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is in your `object[]`?  I take it `test` is an object array itself?

Comment: What is your `object test` initialised as?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939293/remove-null-rows-from-a-string-array-using-linq

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth i have edit the question hope it helps

Comment: @MamtaDalal i need the id's to be intact so that solutions wont work

Comment: If this question would be "How to create a Dictionary from an Array" it would get an upvote from me since it's easy to select only values that are not `null` but it's "difficult" to get the appropriate index without searching it again. I think that using a plain `for loop` without LINQ to create the dictionary is the most straight-forward,readable and fastest way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Select()` overload that supplies the index of the object:

```
test.Select((t,i) => new Sector { id = i, products = t })
.Where(s => s.products != null).ToList();
```

or to get the dictionary:

```
test.Select((t,i) => new Sector { id = i, products = t })
.Where(s => s.products != null).ToDictionary(s => s.id, s => s.products);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dictionary<int,object> keyed = test
    .Select((obj, index) => Tuple.Create(obj, index))
    .Where(x => x.Item1 != null)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Item2, x => x.Item1);
```

Minor note, though - the array will be faster ;p If the array isn't *too* sparse, you might just keep that kicking around.